# Compare words in text with items in listbox

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, text-files

I am writing a code in `c#`, which is supposed read a text file in the look of single words per line . For example :

> "
>   aris
>   kronos
>   aris
>   kronos
>   aris
>   kronos
>   .
>   .
>   "

The code should **read** every **single line** one at the time and write them in a list-box if they do not exist in it.

So the steps should be:

> 1) **read** (the line in the file)
>
> 2) **check** ( if the words is already in the listbox )
>
> 3) If the word does not appear in the listbox creates a **new item** , if it does not **skips** to the next **line**.

The problem I experience in this code, is that the code **compares** the **words** with the **items** in the list box and **skips** to the next one  but , **sometimes it does not** ( it looks like that sometimes it does skip the loop so It does not )

```
string file = @"C:\file.txt";
int Readlines = 0;
int lineNumber = 1;
int AllLines = File.ReadLines(file).Count();
int m = 1;
for (int z = 1; z <= AllLines; z++)
{
       string cLine = File.ReadLines(file).Skip(Readlines).Take(1).First();
       foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
       {
           while (item == cLine || cLine == "")
               {
                    Match_Label.Text = "Found " + m + " matches!";
                    Readlines++;
                    cLine = File.ReadLines(file).Skip(Readlines).Take(1).First();
                    m++;
               }
        }
        string newline =  cLine;
        listBox1.Items.Add(newline);
        Readlines++;
 }
```

Comment: `File.ReadLines` should be thought of as a heavy-duty operation. Do it once, and only once.

Comment: And only do it if you know your files are small. It's better to open a file and use StreamReader.ReadLine() to iterate over each line in the file (for large files). Also, try restructuring your code so that it reads more like your description.

Comment: Can you give an example on lines that go wrong? Does uppercase and lowercase make a difference? Also, is there any white space in front or at the end of the line? Use .trim() to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer that does not rely on those extension methods:

```
        using (var reader = File.OpenText("c:\file.txt"))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (!listBox.Items.Contains(line))
                    listBox.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
```

You can add your output messages and counters once you see that this works. You can also include other conditions, like making sure the line has length > 0 before including it.

Comment: Your code works excellent  but , can you give me a link or an instruction how to understand the using statement to understand how this words?

Comment: You can look up `using` in the MSDN C# Language specification. It is basically a wrapper for an IDisposable type that calls Dispose() on the object when the program flow exists the body of the using. The `reader` object is of type StreamReader, which implements IDisposable. It's Dispose() member is called to free up resources when the code block associated with the using is exited.

Comment: Thank you very much , I will follow your instruction . Have a nice day ( to everyone in this thread )

Answer (score 3):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Distinct();

var result = lines.Union(listBox.Items.Cast<string>()).ToArray();

listBox.DataSource = result;
```

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov,  wouldn't you need to Union the two sets then call Distinct to throw out the duplicates?

Comment: @Lorek - You're right. `Distinct()` can be removed.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but can you exmplain me what the two vars are doing?